# Is it possible get an approximation or to define theoretically the definite integral for a function of the type Weierstrass?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, numerical-methods, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

We define $$\rho(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\text{squarefree}}(n)\cdot\frac{\sin\left(n^2\pi x\right)}{n^2},\tag{1}$$

where the first factor inside the previous series is the characteristic function

$$1_{\text{squarefree}}(n) =
\begin{cases}
1                           & \text {for }n=1 \\
1                           & \text{if } \operatorname{rad}(n) = n \\
0                           & \text{if }\operatorname{rad}(n) < n \\
\end{cases},$$

with $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ denoting the radical of an integer, see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer). Thus $1_{\text{squarefree}}(n)$ is the indicator function of squarefree numbers. See the definiton of this set for example from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squarefree.html) that also provide us the code *SquareFreeQ[n]* that I've used in my toy example:

`plot sum (Boole(SquareFreeQ(n)) Sin(n^2 pi x))/n^2, from n=1 to 100, for 0<x<5`

with the pupose to plot in [Wolfram Alpha online calculator.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Definition $(1)$ is similar than Weierstrass function, see the MathWolrd's entry for [Monsters of Real Analysis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonstersofRealAnalysis.html).

> **Question.** Can you calculate the are under the curve (the graph of) $\rho(x)$ defined in $(1)$ over the interval $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$? If isn't possible explain what handicaps do you find when you've tried to apply your numerical methods and/or definition of integral to get it. **Many thanks.**

Comment: With approximation I am saying an approximation with mathematical meaning using a suitable method from numerical analysis.

Comment: The area is $\frac{1680}{17 \pi^5}$.

Comment: Many thanks @ProfessorVector I believe that this (my question) was a bad question (if I right it is Weiertrass M test and to combine with the theorem saying that a series is uniformly convergent on a bounded interval is integrable) but feel free to add an answer or expand your comment with the purpose to provide to all users your reasonings.

Comment: If you don't learn anything then your question is "bad". There are plenty of books with such exercices and solutions. If you search for analytic-number-theory in MSE you'll find thousands more.

Comment: You are right, what can say? I know  that yours are the best advices @reuns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series is uniformly convergent on $\bigl[0,{1\over2}\bigr]$, hence can be integrated termwise. One obtains
$$\int_0^{1/2}{\sin(n^2\pi x)\over n^2}\>dx=0\quad(n\ {\rm\ even}),\qquad{\rm resp.,}\quad ={1\over\pi n^4}\quad(n\ {\rm\ odd})\ .$$
Now this was not terribly difficult. But anyway, we didn't have to look at the graph of the function at stake.

Comment: Many thanks and I am agree.

Comment: The sum of $\frac1{\pi n^4}$ over all odd, squarefree $n$ can be evaluated in closed form.

Answer (score 1):

As @Christian Blatter pointed out, the integral is $$\frac{1}{\pi}\sum^\infty_{n\,{\rm odd,squarefree}}\frac1{n^4}.$$ Clearly, an odd, squarefree number is a product of distinct, odd primes, so if $P$ is the set of primes, we have $$\sum^\infty_{n\,{\rm odd,squarefree}}\frac1{n^4}=\prod_{p\in P, p\neq2}\left(1+\frac1{p^4}\right)=\frac{16}{17}\prod_{p\in P}\left(1+\frac1{p^4}\right).$$ But $$1+\frac1{p^4}=\frac{1-p^{-8}}{1-p^{-4}},$$ so due to the Euler product for the Zeta function, we have
$$\prod_{p\in P}\left(1+\frac1{p^4}\right)=\frac{\zeta(4)}{\zeta(8)}.$$ With the known special values of the Zeta function for even integer arguments, we get the final result $$\frac{1680}{17\pi^5}.$$

Comment: Many thanks for this answer.